# Pass data to previous composable in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I will take a simple sample.

I have 2 Screens: Screen A and Screen B. From Screen A, I open Screen B. And when I return Screen B to Screen A, I want to transfer data back to Screen A.

With Android Fragment, I can use Shared ViewModel or Fragment Result API to do this.
But with Android Compose, the Fragment Result Api is not in Compose. With using Shard ViewModel, what lifecycle do I have to attach Shared ViewModel so it can keep alive? Activity, ... or something else.

Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you use jetpack navigation, you can pass back data by adding it to the previous back stack entry's savedStateHandle. ([Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result))

Screen **B** passes data back:

```kotlin
composable("B") {
  ComposableB(
    popBackStack = { data ->
      // Pass data back to A
      navController.previousBackStackEntry
        ?.savedStateHandle
        ?.set("key", data)

      navController.popBackStack()
    }
  )
}
```

Screen **A** Receives data:

```kotlin
composable("A") { backStackEntry ->
  // get data passed back from B
  val data: T by backStackEntry
    .savedStateHandle
    .getLiveData<T>("key")
    .observeAsState()

  ComposableA(
    data = data,
    navToB = {
      // optional: clear data so LiveData emits
      // even if same value is passed again
      backStackEntry.savedStateHandle.remove("key")
      // navigate ...
    }
  )
}
```

Replace `"key"` with a unique string, `T` with the type of your data and `data` with your data.

Comment: Yeah. In my project, I am also using `SavedState Handle`, `Navigation`, `Hilt` and `ViewModel`. So I will continue to use `SavedStateHandle` to get the data back.  I just re-read the document of `SavedStateHandle` again.

Thank you!

Comment: @Noah `backStackEntry.savedStateHandle.get<T>("key")` should be enough instead of the livedata getter ?

Comment: also you can access it from `ViewModel` - `savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle` (in constructor of `ViewModel`), no need to pass it as argument to Composable function - `val data = savedStateHandle["key"]`

Comment: @user924, my `ViewModel` doesn't receive new keys for some reason, although `NavGraphBuilder.composable` does receive it. I'm doing exactly as docs show - `previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, value)` before popping the current destination.

Comment: @Calamity did you find any solution. i am also facing same issue.

Comment: @praj, check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76901998/11289869. It is impossible to do without exposing state mutation APIs of the viewmodel

Comment: what if i need to pass data from fragmentC to fragmentA?

Answer (score 6):

Let's say there are two screens.

**1 - FirstScreen** it will receive some data and residing on bottom in back stack  user will land here from Second screen by press back button.

**2 - SecondScreen** it will send/attach some data to be received on previous first screen.

Lets start from **second screen sending data**, for that you can do something like this:

```
                    navController.previousBackStackEntry
                        ?.savedStateHandle
                        ?.set("key", viewModel.getFilterSelection().toString())

                    navController.popBackStack()
```

Now lets **catch that data on first screen** for that you can do some thing like this:

```
if (navController.currentBackStackEntry!!.savedStateHandle.contains("key")) {
        val keyData =
            navController.currentBackStackEntry!!.savedStateHandle.get<String>(
                "key"
            ) ?: ""
    }
```

Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: what if i need to pass data from fragmentC to fragmentA? –

Comment: In that case I prefer to use a shared viewModel between screens @MoustafaEL-Saghier

Comment: okay, many thanks, thought there's something better provided by google team

Answer (score 1):

All of your compose composition operations happens within a single activity view hierarchy thus your ViewModel lifecycle will inevitably be bound to that root activity. It can actually be accessed from your composition through `LocalLifecycleOwner.current`.

Keep in mind that Compose is a **totally different paradigm** than activity/fragment, you can indeed share ViewModel across composables but for the sake of keeping those simple you can also just "share" data simply by passing states using mutable values and triggering **recomposition**.

```kotlin
class MySharedViewModel(...) : ViewModel() {
    var sharedState by mutableStateOf<Boolean>(...)
}

@Composable
fun MySharedViewModel(viewModel: MySharedViewModel = viewModel()) {
    // guessing you already have your own screen display logic
    // This also works with compose-navigator

    ComposableA(stateResult = viewModel.sharedState)
    ComposableB(onUpdate = { viewModel.sharedState = false })
}

fun ComposableA(stateResult: Boolean) {
   ....
}

fun ComposableB(onUpdate: () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = { onUpdate() }) {
        Text("Update ComposableA result")
    }
}
```

Here you'll find further [documentation on managing states with compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodels-source-of-truth)

Comment: Your way is also very well used. But compared with `SavedStateHandle` combined with `Hilt` and `Navigation`, creating more Shared ViewModel is not necessary anymore. :D

Comment: @DươngMinh can you explain more in detail how?