# Jetpack Compose Pages call each other

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have two pages A and B, I navigate from A to B by `navigation`, how can I update the content of A in B.
Both A and B have `ViewModel`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70631089/753632 - You can pass data back that can inform your previous screen to update. Another approach is to use Jetmagic which handles updating any screen from anywhere in your app. See https://github.com/JohannBlake/Jetmagic

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64961032/3585796)