# Jetpack Compose Sending Result Back with SavedStateHandle does not work with SavedStateHandle injected in ViewModel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-navigation, viewmodel-savedstate

Sending Result Back with SavedStateHandle does not work with SavedStateHandle injected in ViewModel.

Getting result using `navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?` it works!

```
fun CreatePostScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    snackbarState: SnackbarHostState,
    viewModel: CreatePostViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {

        navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getStateFlow(
            "result", ""
        )?.collect { result ->
            Timber.d("Result -> $result")
        }
    }
}
```

Using `saveStateHandle` injected using Hilt in ViewModel doesn't get the result!

```
@HiltViewModel
class CreatePostViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {
    
    init {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            savedStateHandle.getStateFlow("result", "").collect {
                Timber.d("Result -> $it")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's how I'm sending the result back to the previous screen!

```
navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("result", "this is result")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The important thing to realize is that every ViewModel instance gets its own `SavedStateHandle` - if you accessed two separate ViewModel classes on the same screen, they would each have their own `SavedStateHandle`.

So when you call `navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle`, you aren't actually getting the `SavedStateHandle` associated with your `CreatePostViewModel` - if you look at the [`NavBackStackEntry` source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:navigation/navigation-common/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/NavBackStackEntry.kt;l=139), you'll note that the `SavedStateHandle` it is returning is for a private ViewModel subclass that is completely independent of any other ViewModels you create.

Therefore if you want to send a result back specifically to your own custom ViewModel (like your `CreatePostViewModel`), you need to specifically ask for exactly that ViewModel in your other screen:

```
// Assumes `it` is the current NavBackStackEntry that was passed to you
// from the composable() lambda
val previousBackStackEntry = remember(it) {
  navController.previousBackStackEntry!!
}
val previousViewModel = hiltViewModel<CreatePostViewModel>(previouslyBackStackEntry)
previousViewModel.savedStateHandle?.set("result", "this is result")
```

Note that with this approach, you need to specifically ask for the ViewModel by its exact class name - that's because the class name is the default `key` that is passed to the [`viewModel()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/package-summary#viewmodel) and similarly for [`hiltViewModel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/hilt/navigation/compose/package-summary#hiltViewModel(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner,kotlin.String)).

Comment: But does your explanation of the problem imply that we cannot generalize `popWithResult` behavior and are doomed to implement `ViewModel`-specific logic provided we do not want to create a kind of `BaseViewModel` with public `SavedStateHandle`?

Comment: And furthermore it necessarily means that we **must** expose `ViewModel`'s state mutation APIs (`savedStateHandle.set(...)`), which is considered bad practice, as UI can theoretically do whatever it wants with it. What do you suppose can one do to combat this?

Comment: @Calamity - that is indeed why you don't see any documentation or official guides that recommend sending results to a specific instance of a ViewModel that allows external classes to mutate it and precisely why the `NavBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle` API exists - to offer that generalized approach that doesn't tightly couple screen together.

Comment: Is there a complete working example not using hilt? I tried using `viewModel(key=previousBackStackEntry.toString())` but it was creating a new `ViewModel` instance.

Comment: @TomBerghuis - `hiltViewModel` and `viewModel` work exactly the same, so you'd use `viewModel<CreatePostViewModel>(previousBackStackEntry)`.